# How do I counteract a rotation from the physics simulation in Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, game-physics, physics-engine

I am creating a game in Unity3D where the player controls a helicopter. I'm moving it by applying forces to its rigidbody-component. The main force comes from the main rotor, pushing the helicopter upwards:

```
rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.up * mainRotorValue);
```

To have it move horizontally I apply a torque to pitch/roll the helicopter, so that the force from the main rotor pushes in some direction other than upwards (in world space):

```
 float tailRotorValue = 0;
 rigidbody.AddRelativeTorque(new Vector3(pitchValue, tailRotorValue, rollValue));
```

When pitched and rolled at the same time, the helicopter will also yaw. I don't really know why, and I don't really want it to happen. My guess at the moment is that there is something in the physics simulation creating this rotation, and that I could calculate some tailRotorValue to counteract it. So I was hoping someone here knew why this rotation occurs, and how I can calculate an opposite force. Or maybe there is a totally different reason and solution to the problem (I'd like to keep the movement physics based)?

Thank you!

**EDIT -** I don't know the relevance of this, but my rigidbody has a mass of 1530, drag of 0.1 and angularDrag of 1.5.

Comment: You probably should look into _quaternions_.

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate a bit more on how I should involve quaternions in this? I've not really given a lot of thought into what the values I send in actually represent, but Unity's [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=De0PoxaKlww) explains that the Vector3 defines both the axis on which torque will be applied, and the magnitude of the torque. In my case I'm sending in a x/z value of 0 to +/-1600, resulting in a pitch/roll of maximum ~30 degrees.

Comment: Can you pleas clarify if you pitch up you want the helicopter to rotate directly up regardless of roll?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow Adrian!

I'm not sure if this is the solution you wanted, but if you want to limit the rotation of a `rigidbody`, you can expand the `Constraints` tab, and set `Freeze Rotation`'s `Y` axis (I think it's the Y axis. Sorry if I got confused and told you the wrong axis :D) rotation off. (Use this method if you don't want to rotate your helicopter at all. But remember, when you do need it to rotate, you can turn off the constraint via a script, rotate the helicopter, and set the constraint on again.)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the welcome and the proposed solution! I am aware of this option, but it will not work in this case. First off, I want the player to be able to rotate around the Y-axis at will, so disabling rotation completely for a period would ruin that freedom. Secondly, the unwanted rotation happens even when Y-rotation is freezed!

Comment: @Adrian Your welcome. I wish you luck on making your game! (By the way, I often get confused which axis is which, as they differ from software to software.)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, guys, I found the problem. There was a bit of code I had written to help stabilize the helicopter, which I chose to omit in my post because *I thought I had made sure it was not the cause*. I'm sorry I wasted your time with an insufficient question, thank you for trying! The lesson I've learned is to make sure to isolate the problem, and to thoroughly test the parts you've isolated.